# browser appends escape \ character to javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, mqtt

I am trying to send an MQTT message to topic from angular app which accepts the message in a specific syntax as follows

```
   {
     "Message": "hello" //the space after : is mandatory
   }
```

but after I send the message in the above format the browser appends \ to the above code as follows

```
"{ \"Message\" : \"hello\" }"
```

which disrupts the actual syntax and the message is not accepted by the topic (`receiver`).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes for the key and value?

Comment: Can you provide the send logic?

Comment: Of course it's an array of objects. It's an object containing a field "Message" with value "hello".

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt yes I have tried

Comment: can you please provide the logic where you have the send code???

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: he does not want the '\' coming in the way when he is sending a request

Comment: Which \? I only see \ to escape " in a string.

Comment: Mqtt works on pub/sub concept so I am sending a message to a topic(kind of reciever) so basically I am publishing a message, the topic receives the message in the format I have provided in my question and those who are subscribed to that topic will receive the message @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS

Comment: yeah the browser appends it how do I prevent it from doing this? @Tvde1

Answer (score 0):

**but once I hit send the browser appends \ to the above code as follows**

What do you mean by "hit send in browser"? How are you sending the MQTT message? Since you seem to be sending a JSON, have you tried to somehow add the following header to the request sending the object:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

As to why your code sample returns an Array, that is because your *str* variable is actually an Array with a single string element. The correct way of parsing your string to a json object would be as follows:

```
var str ="{\"message\": \"hello\"}"
console.log(str)
console.log(JSON.parse(str))
```

Notice the lack of square brackets [] (thus a string and not an array). Also, since str is no longer an array, it no longer has a *map* method, so we just directly call JSON.parse on it.

Note that you could also use single quotes instead of double quotes when declaring strings in javascript, so you could also declare *str* as follows:
    var str ='{"message": "hello"}'
This way you don't need to escape your quotes with backslashes.